# Membership.ValidateUser is Slow

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, authentication, membership

I am using the `System.Web.Sercurity.Membership` methods to deal with users of our web service. I was very happy with it during testing as our database and web service resided on the same server.

When the database and web service where moved to separate servers we are getting a massive delay when we are authenticating users with the `Membership.ValidateUser(username, password)` command.

Config file details:

```
type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, 
      System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,    
      PublicKeyToken=*********" 
connectionStringName="BlaBlaConnection" 
enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" 
RequiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"       
maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6"   
minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" 
applicationName="/"
```

Comment: FYI: The new server has a faster ping time than the last one.

Comment: Ping time is really not indicative of performance at all since it doesn't measure processing time. What is *a massive delay*?

Comment: A ping does not reflect how fast the database responds. Check out what is different about it (maybe database server settings). A ping does not reflect necessary how fast is the connection between database and web service. It may be fast when they are on the same station but things occur differently when they are on different machines (I don't know your deployment settings and connection type so I can't make more assumptions/suggestions). Are you sure it's membership the problem, not anything else regarding the deployment?

Comment: I am having the exact same problem. I've used ANTS Profiler to confirm the delay. It is a > 15 seconds delay period during which there is no browser activity.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was to do with permissions on the database box
This article helped: https://elgg.leeds.ac.uk/webteam/weblog/15385.html

Our Database guy added the App Pool Identity and the Domain machine identity to the database box and .NET root directories granting read/write access.

When the servers were re-imaged the UNC paths for those directories were not on the C: drive so they didn't inherit the "normal" ACL rights

When this was corrected the timings went way down,
**But** it's still a bit slow for what I want (averaging about 4 seconds for  `Membership.ValidateUser(username, password);`
and `Roles.IsUserInRole(username, item.Role)`; with a load of 10,000 per hour)

Comment: The link is down. Do you have another reference to it?